# X2Go and OpenGL applications

Tags: remote-desktop, opengl

I'm using X2Go software for remote desktop access to a home machine running Ubuntu 14.04. I have the `x2goserver` package installed on the server and `x2goclient` installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 client. Both machines have had Ubuntu installed from the same image within the last week. Here is my issue: if I try to run any application that relies on OpenGL from the remote server, I get an error saying that OpenGL is not available on that display. I can verify this with the package `0ad`. This game runs fine on the client machine and when I'm physically in front of the server machine. However, over the X2Go connection, I get the error. Any ideas as to what may be the cause?